# AWS MariaDB mysqldump problem with --host option

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

I have a problem when use `mysqldump` to dump my data from MariaDB instance on AWS, I followed the document from Mysql and MariaDB about `mysqldump` but I got a problem with `--host` option, when use this command:

`mysqldump -h aws_maria_endpoint -u admin -pPassWord database_name > backup.sql`

I always get this error:

`Access denied for user 'admin'@'my_computer_public_ip' (using password: YES)`

I'm using mysql and mariadb on Windows

Please help, thank you so much

Comment: Is your hostname really `aws_maria_endpoint`? Is your password really `PassWord`? Is your database name really `database_name`?

Comment: hi @kmoser,
Yes I do check several times and I'm sure all my input is correct

Comment: Then either your username is not really "root" or the "root" user was not granted access from your IP address. Or, I'd bet you're wrong about my previous questions.

Comment: Hi @kmoser, I figure out the problem, that because I use to much character ``` ! ```, so in a magic way, the mysql can not read all of that character, after I change my MariaDB password everything is working fine now!